# Derivation of Square-Root Computation Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, proof-explanation

In this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Decimal_.28base_10.29) , an algorithm for computing the square root of a number is given using pencil and paper in base 10.

Why does it works? How to derive it?

I know that it is derived using $r$ as the error with  $(X+r)^2 = X^2+2Xr+r^2$.

But how do I iterate it ?

Comment: Did you read the section right above what you linked to? It explains the process pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Consider finding the square root of $(10x+y)^2=100x^2+20xy+y^2$. In the given method, you first compute $x$. Afterwards, you multiply it by 2 and compute $(20x+y)y$. So you basically compute $100 x^2 + (20x+y)y = 100x^2+20xy+y^2=(10x+y)^2$.